# Detection of static and dynamic pedestrians from sparse 3D point clouds

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, point-clouds, lidar

I want to use point clouds to detect static and dynamic people. However, I use **VLP-16** and it is obvious the point clouds will be very sparse in the vertical direction.

I have study related literatures such as use deep learning (PointNet, PointPillar, SECOND, PointRCNN...) or machine learning (SVM), but most methods not fit my need.

Are there some methods that take my need (**detect static and dynamic people use lidar only**)?
If so, could you possibly tell me how to achieve that?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I think these repositories will help you to solve your problem.

1. https://github.com/tusimple/LiDAR_RCNN
2. https://github.com/trinhkle07/pedestrians-3d-detection
3. https://github.com/praveen-palanisamy/multiple-object-tracking-lidar

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am looking for some methods that find people property (gender, height...) after detecting. Besides, I want to implement these features on a drone, with the limited computational power, I need efficient algorithms to achieve real-time performance.